# Evaluate $1$-loop contribution to the $4$-point Green's function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, renormalization, integration

I am trying to evaluate the following integral
\begin{equation}
I = \int \frac{d^d p_\text{E}}{(2 \pi)^d} \frac{1}{(p_\text{E}^2+m^2)((q_\text{E}-p_\text{E})^2 + m^2)} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $p_\text{E}$ is the momentum in *Euclidean* space (i.e. after having performed a Wick rotation). Using [Feynman's parametrization trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_parametrization), and some effort, equation $(1)$ can be written as:
\begin{equation}
I = \int\limits^1_0 \mathrm{d} x \int \frac{d^d p'_\text{E}}{(2 \pi)^d} \frac{1}{\left[p_\text{E}'^2 + q_\text{E}^2 x(1-x) + m^2 \right]^2} \tag{2}
\end{equation}
where $p'_\text{E} = p_\text{E} - q(1-x)$. I know that equation $(2)$ is correct as I have verified by checking 2 different sources. Now, according to the two aforementioned sources, equation $(2)$  can be written evaluated as:
\begin{equation}
I = \frac{\pi^{d/2}}{(2 \pi)^d} \Gamma(2-d/2) \int\limits^1_0 \mathrm{d} x \; (q_\text{E}^2 x(1-x) + m^2)^{d/2-2} \tag{3}
\end{equation}
where $\Gamma(2-d/2)$ is the [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). However, I don't know where this comes from.

So far, the closest I have come is by writing equation $(2)$ as:
\begin{equation}
I = \int\limits^1_0 \mathrm{d} x \int \frac{d^d p'_\text{E}}{(2 \pi)^d} \int\limits^\infty_0 \mathrm{d}u \int\limits^\infty_0 \mathrm{d}u \; e^{-u(p_\text{E}'^2 + q_\text{E}^2 x(1-x) + m^2 )}  \tag{4}
\end{equation}
We can perform the integration over $p'_\text{E}$ by using Gaussian integration:
\begin{equation}
\int \mathrm{d}^d p_{\text{E}} \;  e^{-up'^2_{\text{E}}} = \left(\frac{\pi}{u}\right)^{d/2}
\end{equation}
Thus equation $(4)$ becomes:
\begin{equation}
I = \frac{\pi^{d/2}}{(2 \pi)^d} \int\limits^1_0 \mathrm{d} x \int\limits^\infty_0 \mathrm{d}u \int\limits^\infty_0 \mathrm{d}u \; u^{-d/2}e^{-u(q_\text{E}^2 x(1-x) + m^2 )}  \tag{5}
\end{equation}
Now, letting:
\begin{equation}
w = \left(q_\text{E}^2 x(1-x) + m^2 \right) u \Rightarrow \mathrm{d} u = \left(q_\text{E}^2 x(1-x) + m^2 \right)^{-1} \; \mathrm{d} w
\end{equation}
and substituting the above into equation $(5)$ yields:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
I & = \frac{\pi^{d/2}}{(2 \pi)^d} \int\limits^1_0 \mathrm{d} x \int\limits^\infty_0 \mathrm{d}w \int\limits^\infty_0 \mathrm{d}w \; w^{-d/2}e^{-w} \left(q_\text{E}^2 x(1-x) + m^2 \right)^{d/2-2} \\&
= \frac{\pi^{d/2}}{(2 \pi)^d} \int\limits^1_0 \mathrm{d} x \int\limits^\infty_0 \mathrm{d}w \; \Gamma(1-d/2) \left(q_\text{E}^2 x(1-x) + m^2 \right)^{d/2-2} \tag{6}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
At this point I'm stuck. I have no idea if the steps taken to get to equation $(6)$ are correct, but equation $(6)$ does kind of look like equation $(3)$ so I hope they are. Could anybody help me and tell me how I can derive equation $(3)$?

Comment: The expression you mentioned is known as "the master formula" when doing loop calculations. QFT books probably have a derivation of it. I am pretty sure Peskin and Schroeder do, when they introduce these techniques.

Comment: @JeffDror I have looked at P&S, but couldn't find anything. Maybe I have missed it; I will check again.

Comment: @JeffDror what expression in my original post is known as "the master formula". I can't find anything in P&S which could resolve my problem.

Comment: I was referring to equation 3. This equation and its modifications are derived on pg. 249-251. The set of master formula in Minkowski space (i.e., you avoid the hassle of Wick rotation) are just quoted in the appendix, p.g. 807.

Comment: Also, I think you have a typo on your equation 6. I don't think it needs the extra $w$ integration.

Comment: @JeffDror Thanks for your reply. Why don't you think the extra $w$ integration is necessary? In equation $(4)$ I am already using two $u$ integrations, do you think that is wrong as well?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look very carefully. I just assumed there was a mistake since you were integrating over the same variable twice. I didn't get a chance to follow the entire post yet.

Comment: @JeffDror ok, no problem. If you do get a chance to have a look at some point in the future, then I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the answer given by soliton is sufficient, I've found a way to explicitly evaluate this integral (in case anybody might be interested). Let us start from equation $(2)$ in the original message:
\begin{equation}
I = \int\limits^1_0 \mathrm{d} x \int \frac{d^d p'_\text{E}}{(2 \pi)^d} \frac{1}{\left[p_\text{E}'^2 + q_\text{E}^2 x(1-x) + m^2 \right]^2} \tag{2}
\end{equation}
This can be written as:
\begin{equation}
I = \int\limits_0^1 \mathrm{d}x \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^d p_{\text{E}}'}{(2\pi)^d} \int\limits^\infty_0 \mathrm{d} u_1 \; e^{- u_1 \left( p_{\text{E}}'^2 + q_\text{E}^2 x(1-x) + m^2 \right)}  \int\limits^\infty_0 \mathrm{d} u_2 \; e^{- u_2 \left( p_{\text{E}}'^2 +q_\text{E}^2 x(1-x) + m^2 \right)} 
\end{equation}
The integration over $p_{\text{E}}'$ becomes an ordinary Gaussian integral:
\begin{equation}
\int \mathrm{d}^d p_{\text{E}}' \; e^{-p_{\text{E}}'^2(u_1+u_2)} = \left( \frac{\pi}{u_1+u_2} \right)^{d/2}
\end{equation}
and so:
\begin{equation}
I = \frac{1}{(4 \pi)^{d/2}} \int\limits_0^1 \mathrm{d}x \int\limits^\infty_0 \mathrm{d} u_1 \int\limits^\infty_0 \mathrm{d} u_2 \; \left(\frac{1}{u_1+u_2}\right)^{d/2} e^{- \left( q_\text{E}^2 x(1-x) + m^2 \right)\left(u_1+u_2 \right)} \tag{3}
\end{equation}
We can make the following substitution:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cc}
u_1 = sx \; ,& u_2 = s(1-x)
\end{array}
\end{equation}
where $0 < s < \infty$ (and of course $0 < x < 1$), such that:
\begin{equation}
u_1+u_2=s \; \; \; \text{and} \; \; \; J = \left|\frac{\partial(u_1,u_2)}{\partial(x,s)} \right| = s
\end{equation}
Thus, equation $(3)$ becomes:
\begin{equation}
I = \frac{1}{(4 \pi)^{d/2}} \int\limits_0^1 \mathrm{d}x \int\limits^\infty_0 \mathrm{d} s \; s^{1-d/2} e^{- \left( q_\text{E}^2 x(1-x) + m^2 \right)s}
\end{equation}
Now, we make the substitution:
\begin{equation}
w = \left( q_\text{E}^2 x(1-x) + m^2 \right)s \Rightarrow \mathrm{d} s = \left( q_\text{E}^2 x(1-x) + m^2 \right)^{-1} \mathrm{d} w
\end{equation}
such that:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
I & = \frac{1}{(4 \pi)^{d/2}} \int\limits_0^1 \mathrm{d}x \int\limits^\infty_0 \mathrm{d} w \; w^{1-d/2} e^{- w} \left( q_\text{E}^2 x(1-x) + m^2 \right)^{d/2-2} \\& 
= \frac{1}{(4 \pi)^{d/2}} \Gamma(2-d/2) \int\limits_0^1 \mathrm{d}x \;  \left( q_\text{E}^2 x(1-x) + m^2 \right)^{d/2-2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 4):

You can prove a general formula
$$
  \int\frac{d^dp_{\mathrm{E}}}{(2\pi)^d}
  \frac{(p_{\mathrm{E}}^2)^m}{(p_{\mathrm{E}}^2+\Delta)^n}=
  \frac{1}{(4\pi)^{d/2}}\frac{\Gamma(m+d/2)\Gamma(n-m-d/2)}{\Gamma(d/2)\Gamma(n)}
  \left(\frac{1}{\Delta}\right)^{n-m-d/2},\quad n>m+d/2
$$
by using Gaussian integral and Euler integral of the first kind.

Comment: Thanks, however I am not sure how to apply it to the above problem. According to your identity, $n=2$ and $m=0$, thus: $$I = \frac{1}{(4 \pi)^{d/2}} \frac{\Gamma(d/2)\Gamma(2-d/2)}{\Gamma(d/2)\Gamma(2)} (\Delta)^{2-d/2}$$ which is not equal to equation $(3)$.

Comment: And $\Delta=q_{\mathrm{E}}^2x(1-x)+m^2$, it is independent of $p_{\mathrm{E}}$.

Comment: Ahhh ok, so it does look very similar. What has happened to the $\int\limits^1_0 \mathrm{d} x$ part that should go in front of $(\Delta)^{2-d/2}$ (see equation $(3)$)?

Comment: We cannot obtain an analytical expression of the integral (3). For $d=4$, (1) is log divergent.

Comment: For $m^2=0$, (3) can be expressed by the Euler integral.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I'm being daft, but I still don't understand how your identity yields: \begin{equation}
I = \frac{\pi^{d/2}}{(2 \pi)^d} \Gamma(2-d/2) \int\limits^1_0 \mathrm{d} x \; (q_\text{E}^2 x(1-x) + m^2)^{d/2-2}
\end{equation} Although it becomes similar to that equation.

Comment: The $\int_0^1d x$ is copyed from (2). The two $I$s are not the same in your comments.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right, I was not paying enough attention. Thank you!